# TypeError: getComputedStyle in JointsWP

Tags: jquery, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I've used JointsWP many times now, and have never encountered this error. I have tried disabling all plugins, but only when deactivating ACF Pro (which esentially gives me a blank website) is the error removed. The only place on the site where this appears to be causing an issue is the mobile menu not firing.

Some of the research I've done points to the way jQuery is called for, which I know WordPress is particular about. I'm not sure why this would only now be a problem with Foundation. Is it possible there is some kind of conflict?

See below for list of errors. I am running the current version of WordPress and ACF Pro. [Here is my website.](http://delinstaging.wpengine.com/)

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a Foundation call in my header.php file that connected it to off-canvas-topbar.php. Be sure "data-off-canvas-wrapper" is included (as of v6.2).